# The process cannot access the file yyyy because it is being used by another process

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, visual-studio, filestream

I store files in a SQL Server database, and I also to show the files in my application if a user select them. this is what I have done:

```
LetterBAL letterBal = new LetterBAL();
string filter = "Id=" + letterListView.SelectedItems[0].Text;

Letter letter = letterBal.GetLetterImage(filter);        

string path = System.Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments);
path = path + "\\IssuedLetter\\" +letter.Id.ToString() + "." +letter.FileExt;                

webBrowser1.Navigate(path);


public Letter GetLetterImage(string filter)
{
      LetterDB letterDB = new LetterDB();
      Letter letter = letterDB.GetLetterImage(filter);

      string path = System.Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments);
      path = path + "\\IssuedLetter";
      path = path + "\\" + letter.Id.ToString() + "." + letter.FileExt;               

      using (var fs = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write))
      fs.Write(letter.ltr_Image, 0, letter.ltr_Image.Length);           
      return letter;
}
```

The first time that users select a file , it's been shown in web browser without problem. But if for second time (when the web browser still is showing the same pdf file) it says

> The process cannot access the file  'C:\Users\mj.PG\Documents\IssuedLetter\3.PDF' because it is being used by another process.

How can I handle the situation if the user clicks the same file again to view it?

Comment: Check if the file exists before writing to it? Or write the files there as they're added to the database, rather than when they're being displayed

Comment: I want user be able to overwrite the file(maybe he has changed something on it)

Comment: Yes, but your code isn't doing that. Next time someone views it, it will be re-overwritten by `GetLetterImage`. Handle persisting to disk when a user adds or edits the file, not on read.

Comment: so what should I do if the file is set for webbrowser.navigate(thesamefile)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several ways to avoid blocking:

1. Do not use intermediate files at all, use [DocumentStream](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.webbrowser.documentstream(v=vs.110).aspx) property of WebBrowser and MemoryStream as a source.
2. Use new temporary file name for each Letter. Do not forget cleanup procedure on the application closing.
3. Most flexible and more time-consuming way is to embed a little http server in your application, for instance based on [OWIN self-hosting](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt152002(v=vs.113).aspx) components. So you additionally could build modern html-based user interfaces with authentication, authorization and other functionality. As a bonus, your application could be accessible from other computers in local network and easily implement Windows service, if you want.